# Android Intent makes my app crash, why?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-layout, android-intent

so I tried out my app without passing the score variable, and it worked. But If I try to use it, it won't work at all.

main class:

```
int start = 10;



// start Play Intent
public void onPlay(View view){
    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, Quiz_1.class);
    playIntent.putExtra("Score", start);
    startActivity(playIntent);
}
```

and the `Quiz_1` class:

```
public class Quiz_1 extends Activity {
int printScore;
TextView printPoints;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_1);
    printPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);
}

Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
String printFin = String.valueOf(score);

public void q_result(View view){
    printPoints.setText(printFin);
}
```

I am sure, I did something wrong when I tried to pass the start value to my other activity. There I wanted to change a textView's text to the previous  int start value = 10;

So, 
First activity:
int t start = 10;

Second. activity:
int score = start; 
printScore(it's a TextView) setText = score

Comment: `It won't work`,  What does that mean?

Comment: did you declare Quiz_1 in the manifest?

Comment: you have few lines of code outside any method

Comment: so, what should i change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass a value to another intent, you can look into the code below.

You can put key value pairs like in intents and you can retrieve these values in the activity you are calling. You can look into :-

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, SecondActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("name","abc");
startActivity(returnIntent,11);
```

And in you other activity result method, you can do

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras != null) {
String name = bundle.getString("name");
    // and get whatever data you are adding
}
```

You can look into this.

Comment: but if i want to pass more than one variable? but not from the same class, i would pass a default score variable to this acitivity via intent but i would also pass another value from a different activity? –

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are trying to say, but u can pass unlimited number of key value pairs by calling the putExtra method.

Comment: i will edit your answer, so you can understand me, i will copy my code which does not work, okay?

Answer (score 0):

All Java code must be in a method.  Here, the last three lines are not in any method and are therefore not executed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_1);
    printPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);

} <----- move this closing brace

Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
String printFin = String.valueOf(score);    

} <----- to here
```

Comment: do i need methods for every single thing in a class?

Comment: not executed???? That`s wrong. Probably you meant that getIntent(), at that time, returns null?

Comment: thank you, you are the best programmer in the world!!!!!!!!! you are the godd of programming!! thank you so much, you helped a lot and you saved my life!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @blackbelt getIntent() will never execute.  It is outside any method.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped.  Please accept the answer by clicking the tick.  BTW, I am very far from the best programmer in the world.  This is first week in Java school ;)

Comment: @Simon while the solution is correct, the reason is not 100% correct. This is because when the class (`Activity`, in this context) is created, the variables will be initialized with the value (it's possible to use the returned value of a method). That means, those 3 lines will be executed **before** `onCreate()` is called, returning `null` to `intent`. Therefore, throwing `NullPointerException` on `intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0)`, just as @blackbelt said.

Comment: @blackbelt. Ah, yes,  Now I see. Antimo.  You are correct.  user2547460 Please un-accept my answer and select one of the others.

Comment: @blackbelt  When is code outside a method executed?  Is it when the class is loaded?  If I have a static initialiser, is it executed before or after that?  2 years with Android and Java and I always believed that code must be inside a method.

Comment: but if i want to pass more than one variable? but not from the same class, i would pass a default score variable to this acitivity via intent but i would also pass another value from a different activity? –

Comment: Please read the documentation for `Intent`, `getExtras()` and `Bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have these inside a method like `onCreate`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
String printFin = String.valueOf(score);
```

However the crash may still happen so better post the stack trace

Edit:

```
String printFin; //declare as class member
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_1);
    printPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
    printFin = String.valueOf(score);
}
```

Comment: @user2547460 also declare `String printFin` as class member if not it is local to `onCreate` and you are using it in `q_result`

Comment: but if i want to pass more than one variable? but not from the same class, i would pass a default score variable to this activity via intent but i would also pass another value from a different activity? –

Answer (score 0):

change all your code to

```
public class Quiz_1 extends Activity {
int printScore;
TextView printPoints;


int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.quiz_1);

     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) 
     {
       score   = extras.getInt("Score");
    }


    printPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);
 printPoints.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
```

Comment: there is method `public void q_result(View view){
    printPoints.setText(printFin);
}` in the op code where is it?

Comment: why do i need to use if and extras = null, doesn;t make sense and complicated and why use if statement if it can work without ti??? please explain !!!

Comment: @user2547460 the if is to check if extras is null its just a check good to have. but you have method on button click you need to set the text but there there is no `public void q_result(View view){ printPoints.setText(printFin); }`

Comment: @Jack K Foani what if extras is null still   `printPoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_result);
 printPoints.setText(String.valueOf(score));` this is executed?

Comment: if its still null its mean the activity who started `Quiz_1` class dose not send intent extra `Score` , so you can't use extra because its empty on first check if null , the Score will be set as 0 original defined in your `Quiz_1` class, but if Extras not null the `Score` will be changed to new Score was sent to activity by intent.putExtra

Comment: but if i want to pass more than one variable? but not from the same class, i would pass a default score variable to this acitivity via intent but i would also pass another value from a different activity?

Comment: @user2547460 ask a new question the question you asked is already answered. got a new question start a new thread

Comment: ohh please, it's below I edited someone's answer, i will accept yours if you can help me, it's a homework, due tomorrow, I will get an F, and I dont have time, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through this link - http://pastebin.com/BGAkdeCv

I may have found an error

Case 1 : - You are passing the defaultScore value in passScore key and retrieving it in Quiz1.Java
MainActivity.Java ->

```
startQuiz.putExtra("passScore", defaultScore);
```

Quiz_1.Java ->

```
  current_score   = extras.getInt("passScore");
```

Case 2 : - You are passing current_score in passNewScore and retrieving it in Quiz2.Java
Quiz_1.Java ->

```
   quiz1.putExtra("passNewScore", current_score);
```

Quiz2.Java

```
  current_score   = extras.getInt("passScore");
  getScore = extras.getInt("passNewScore");
```

Now, the error here is :-
in quiz2.java where you are extracting **passScore in current_score** because this key value was put in your main_activity, not your quiz1.java from where you are calling quiz2.java.,.

so to retrieve this value in quiz2.java, you have to pass it again in quiz1.java from where you are calling quiz2 intent

To correct it modify your quiz1.java :-

```
public void on_quiz_1_wrong(View view){  // button clicked the wrong answer
   current_score = current_score - 2;
   Intent quiz1 = new Intent(this, Quiz_2.class);
   startActivity(quiz1);
   quiz1.putExtra("passNewScore", current_score);
   quiz1.putExtra("passScore", whatever value you want to pass here);

}
```